# Object has "Undefined Properties" that are actually defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the package: https://packagist.org/packages/gavroche/ups-api

I'm getting some odd behaviors from Laravels Exception Handler when I run this:

```
$tracking = new \UPS\Tracking(
        'KEY', 'USERNAME', 'PASS'
        );

$shipment = $tracking->track('TRACKING NUMBER HERE');

foreach($shipment->Package->Activity as $activity) {
    var_dump($activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City);
}
```

The interesting thing is the cities are var_dumped however laravels exception handler, in the same breath, says Undefined property: stdClass::$City.

Here is a vardump of one of the $activity objects:

```
object(stdClass)[518]

  public 'ActivityLocation' => 

    object(stdClass)[519]

      public 'Address' => 

        object(stdClass)[520]

          public 'City' => string 'CLEVELAND' (length=9)

          public 'StateProvinceCode' => string 'TN' (length=2)

          public 'PostalCode' => string '37311' (length=5)

          public 'CountryCode' => string 'US' (length=2)

      public 'Code' => string 'M4' (length=2)

      public 'Description' => string 'RECEPTION' (length=9)

      public 'SignedForByName' => string 'HICKMAN' (length=7)

  public 'Status' => 

    object(stdClass)[521]

      public 'StatusType' => 

        object(stdClass)[522]

          public 'Code' => string 'D' (length=1)

          public 'Description' => string 'DELIVERED' (length=9)

      public 'StatusCode' => 

        object(stdClass)[523]

          public 'Code' => string 'KB' (length=2)

  public 'Date' => string '20130426' (length=8)

  public 'Time' => string '085500' (length=6)
```

Any property in the $activity->ActivityLocation->Address object laravel sees issue with. However, I can request $activity->Status->StatusType->Description and there are no problems.

A regular for loop fixes the issue. Seems to be some issue in the incrementing of php's foreach().

```
for ($i=0; $i < (count($shipment->Package->Activity) - 1); $i++) { 
    var_dump($shipment->Package->Activity[$i]->ActivityLocation->Address->City);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not clear on this, but are you trying to access this as

```
$activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City ?
```

You left the `$activity` part off your question and used `$City` and not `City`, and I wasnt sure if this was intentional or not

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'm trying to access the city property via $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City.